# Stock reduce after purchase

Tags: php, mysql

this code about invoice generate and print the invoice section. after purchase multiple product or single product should reduce quantity from the bincard table. what is the solution for this. my code insert database section working perfectly but the problem is quantity not reduce from the bincard table. i have tried myself but still not get solution for this.

```
<?php
global $con;

if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
$id = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$SalesPerson = $_POST['SalesPerson'];
$Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
$CustomerName = $_POST['CustomerName'];


$socupay = $_POST['socupay'];
$sobalance = $_POST['sobalance'];
$itemList = $_POST['demo'];
$namet=$_POST['item_name'];
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
$i=0;
$j=1;


foreach($namet as $name1)
{

$quantity=$_POST['Quantity'][$i];

$count = "SELECT count(*) FROM bincard WHERE ItemName='$name1' and QtyIssued >=$Quantity";
if($count == 1)
{

$amount = "SELECT QtyIssued FROM bincard WHERE ItemName='$name1'";
$amount1 = $amount - $Quantity;

$db->execute("UPDATE bincard SET QtyIssued=$amount1 WHERE ItemName='$name1'");
$j++;
}
else
{
echo "<br><font color=green size=+1 >There is no enough stock deliver for $name1! Please add stock !</font>" ;
}
$i++;
}


if( $socupay == NULL && $itemList == NULL)
{
echo"<script> alert('Please fill all the fields')</script>";
}
else
{           
$sql = "insert into invoiceorder (InvoId,Date,SalesPerson,Telephone,Customer,CurrentPayment,Balance) 
values ('$id','$date','$SalesPerson','$Telephone','$CustomerName','$socupay','$sobalance')";

$sql1 = $itemList;

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$query1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);


if($query && $query1)
{
echo "<script>alert('Press ok to print!')</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('invoiceprint.php?id=$id','_self')</script>";
}   
else
{
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}       
}

}
?>
```

Comment: `$count = "SELECT count(*) FROM bincard WHERE ItemName='$name1' and QtyIssued >=$Quantity";` and `if($count == 1)`  you are comparing the string `"SELECT count(*) FROM bincard WHERE ItemName='$name1"` with a number 1 instead off executing the query and fetch the COUNT(*) results.

Comment: In addition to what Raymond commented, you need to be aware of sql injection.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  - how i do this. im not a good programmer